# What is causing the NaN error in my TS code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I admit this is probably a basic thing for a TS developer, but I've taken over an application as a non-Typescript expert/developer. I've tried to use my own best intuition to figure it out, but I'm not having any luck at this point.

It's the totalAmountDue line at the bottom that's giving me fits. The calculation works great and outputs the correct value until I add addlDonationLoadCost to it. The intellisence indicates addlDonationLoadCost is number type but the calculation outputs NaN. I also get "cannot find name 'otherGrossProceedsDollar'" error when I add it to the calculation.

Here is the code:

```
port const saleToInvoice = sale => {
    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    function toCurrency(str) {
        if (!isNumber(str)) {
            return 'NaN'
        }
        var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
        });

        return formatter.format(str);
        //return isNumber(str) ? `$ ${parseFloat(str).toFixed(2)}` : 'NaN'
    }

    const transactions8To10 = isNumber(sale.transactions8To10) ? sale.transactions8To10 : (!sale.transactions8To10 || sale.transactions8To10.trim() === '' ? '0' : 'NaN')
    const transactionsOpeningDay = isNumber(sale.transactionsOpeningDay) ? sale.transactionsOpeningDay : (!sale.transactionsOpeningDay || sale.transactionsOpeningDay.trim() === '' ? '0' : 'NaN')
    const transactionTotal = isNumber(sale.transactionTotal) ? sale.transactionTotal : (!sale.transactionTotal || sale.transactionTotal.trim() === '' ? '0' : 'NaN')
    const commissionRateTotal = parseFloat(`${sale.commissionRate/100 * sale.grossSalesActualClover}`)
    // const totalTrueLegacyFee = parseFloat(sale.minimumActual) + commissionRateTotal
    
    
    //const grossSalesEntireSale = parseFloat(sale.grossSalesCreditDebit || sale.grossSalesCash)

    //Gross Sales Cash + Cash Outside Clover + (Gross Sales Credit & Debit*0.965) – (Gross Sales Actual Clover*0.0775)
    const grossProceeds = parseFloat(sale.grossSalesCash) + parseFloat(sale.cashOutsideClover) +
        (parseFloat(sale.grossSalesCreditDebit) * 0.965) -
        (parseFloat(sale.grossSalesActualClover) * 0.0775);
    const grossProceedsHelp = `Gross Sales Cash + Cash Outside Clover + (Gross Sales Credit & Debit*0.965) - (Gross Sales Actual Clover*0.0775)@${sale.grossSalesCash} + ${sale.cashOutsideClover} + (${sale.grossSalesCreditDebit}*0.965) - (${sale.grossSalesActualClover}*0.0775)`

    

    //(Gross Proceeds – True Legacy Fee Minimum)*True Legacy Fee % = $
    const trueLegacyFeeMinimum = parseFloat(sale.minimumActual);
    const splitFeeFloat = parseInt(sale.splitFee) / 100;
    const trueLegacyFee = (grossProceeds - trueLegacyFeeMinimum) * splitFeeFloat
    const totalTrueLegacyFee = trueLegacyFeeMinimum + trueLegacyFee
    // const netShareToClient = parseFloat(sale.grossSalesActualClover) - totalTrueLegacyFee
    const netShareToClient = grossProceeds - totalTrueLegacyFee
    const trueLegacyFeeHelp = `(Gross Proceeds - True Legacy Fee Minimum)*True Legacy Fee %@(${grossProceeds} - ${trueLegacyFeeMinimum}) * ${splitFeeFloat}`

    const grossSales8To10 = parseFloat(sale.grossSales8To10) * 0.9;
    const grossSales8To10Help = `90% of Gross Sales Opening Day 8-10@${parseFloat(sale.grossSales8To10)} * 0.9`;
    const grossSalesOpeningDay = parseFloat(sale.grossSalesOpeningDay) * 0.9;
    const grossSalesOpeningDayHelp = `90% of Gross Sales Opening Day@${parseFloat(sale.grossSalesOpeningDay)} * 0.9`;
    const disposal = parseFloat(sale.disposalFee)
    const addlDonationLoadCost = parseFloat(sale.additionalDonationLoadCost)
    const courtesyDiscount = parseFloat(sale.courtesyDiscount)
return {
        ...sale,
        transactions8To10,
        transactionsOpeningDay,
        transactionTotal,

        saleId: sale._id,
        clientEmail: sale.clientEmail.toLowerCase(),
        MailingAddress: ["clientMailingAddress1", "clientMailingAddress2", "clientMailingCity"
            , "clientMailingState", "clientPostalCode"].reduce((acc, cur) => sale[cur] && sale[cur] !== '0' ? `${acc}, ${sale[cur]}` : acc, '')
            .substring(1).trim(),
        grossProceeds: toCurrency(grossProceeds), grossProceedsHelp,
        trueLegacyFeeMinimum: toCurrency(trueLegacyFeeMinimum),
        trueLegacyFee: toCurrency(trueLegacyFee), trueLegacyFeeHelp,
        totalTrueLegacyFee: toCurrency(`${totalTrueLegacyFee}`),
        netShareToClient: toCurrency(`${netShareToClient}`),
        disposal: toCurrency(sale.disposalFee),
        

        grossSales8To10: toCurrency(grossSales8To10), grossSales8To10Help,
        avePurchaseAmount8To10: toCurrency(`${grossSales8To10 / parseInt(transactions8To10)}`),

        grossSalesOpeningDay: toCurrency(grossSalesOpeningDay), grossSalesOpeningDayHelp,
        avePurchaseAmountOpeningDay: toCurrency(`${grossSalesOpeningDay / parseInt(transactionsOpeningDay)}`),

        grossSalesEntireSale: toCurrency(`${grossProceeds}`),
        avePurchaseAmountEntireSale: toCurrency(`${grossProceeds / parseInt(transactionTotal)}`),

        courtesyDiscount: toCurrency(courtesyDiscount), hasCourtesyDiscount: sale.courtesyDiscount > 0,


        otherGrossProceedsText: sale.otherGrossProceedsText, hasOtherGrossProceedsText: sale.otherGrossProceedsText && sale.otherGrossProceedsText.trim(),
        otherGrossProceedsDollar: toCurrency(sale.otherGrossProceedsDollar), hasOtherGrossProceedsDollar: sale.otherGrossProceedsDollar > 0,
        addlDonationLoadCost: toCurrency(addlDonationLoadCost),

        totalAmountDue: toCurrency(`${netShareToClient - disposal + courtesyDiscount - addlDonationLoadCost + otherGrossProceedsDollar}`)
        // totalAmountDue: toCurrency(`${addlDonationLoadCost}`)
    
    }
```

Comment: You have no variable named `otherGrossProceedsDollar`, hence it's `undefined`. Adding `undefined` to any number will yield `NaN`. As for the types, as misleading as it may sound at first`NaN` is of type `number`. It's the special value used to indicate that while the result is a number, the value makes no sense. For example `Infinity - Infinity` returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this had nothing to do with the TypeScript. It was actually a typo in the database field name related to additionalDonationLoadCost. The field this relates to was misnamed additionalDonationLoanCost in the db collection.